# Find an alternating permutation of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Given a list, I want to generate a permutation of the list that is alternating: the first element must be greater than the second, which must be lower than the third, which must be greater than the second, etc.

I have tried the following code:

```py
li=[10,2,11,13,21,12,6,7,8,9]
#  condition = a1>a2<a3>a4.....>an

li = sorted(li)
print(li)

for i in range(len(li)-1):
  li[i], li[i+1] = li[i+1], li[i]
  print(li[i],li[i+1])
print(li)
```

But it doesn't satisfy the condition. It gives the Output as below-

```
'[2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 21]'
'[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 2]'
```

Comment: add a code that show output

Comment: Note that something like `a1> a2 <a3 > a4.....>an` doesn't make much sense. Chaining inequalities that are all oriented in the same direction makes sense, because the relation "greater than" is transitive. But from `a1 > a2` and `a2 < a3`, nothing can be deduced about `a1 vs. a3`. Now, python has its own way to chain comparison operators, but when you add `...` in the middle of it, it's neither python nor logic, and pretty hard to understand. Perhaps you'd be better off listing the individual inequalities that you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved rather efficiently with only a few steps:

```py
>>> li=[10,2,11,13,21,12,6,7,8,9]
>>> # sort from smallest to largest
>>> li.sort()
>>> result = [None] * len(li)
>>> # use first/smallest half for a2, a4, a6, ...
>>> result[1::2] = li[:len(li)//2]
>>> # use second/largest half for a1, a3, a5, ...
>>> result[::2] = li[len(li)//2:]
>>> result
[10, 2, 11, 6, 12, 7, 13, 8, 21, 9]
```

The `[::2]` and `[1::2]` are a ["slice from 0/1 with step 2"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), i.e. the odd/even positions.

---

Now why does this work?

Let's look at a small case first:

> a1 > a2 < a3 > a4

We can rewrite this to separate criteria for each element:

- a1 > a2
- a3 > a2 and a3 > a4
- a2 < a1 and a2 < a3
- a4 < a3

These are only between *each* odd element and *several* even elements, and likewise between *each* even element and *several* odd elements. There are no relations between odd elements and no relations between even elements. This means there are several possible solutions and we can pick the one that works easiest:
Instead of worrying about the many *triples* of elements – like a2 a3 a4 – and how they relate to each other, it would be simpler if we could look at the two *even/odd* element groups at once.

We can do this by extending our relation between *each* odd element to *all* even elements and vice versa:

- a1 > a2 **and a1 > a4**
- a3 > a2 and a3 > a4
- a2 < a1 and a2 < a3
- **a4 < a1 and** a4 < a3

This still satisfies the initial criteria, it just excludes *some* possible solution.
Now, if we compare the rules for all odd elements, we can see that they are exactly the same and likewise for all even elements:

- a*i* > a2 and a*i* > a4 for all *i* in {1, 3}
- a*j* < a1 and a*j* < a3 for all *i* in {2, 4}

In fact, both are just a single rule for all elements:

- a*i* > a*j* for all *i* in {1, 3} for all *i* in {2, 4}

At this point, it should be obvious<sup>1</sup> that this does not just apply to the case of 4 elements but in fact to every number of elements:

- a*i* > a*j* for all *i* in {1, 3, ...} for all *i* in {2, 4, ...}

In words, this means *a* possible solution is to have *all* odd elements larger than *all* even elements. This can be achieved by splitting the sorted input to get the largest/smallest elements, then assigning each of these groups to the even/odd positions.

---

<sup>1</sup>The proof is left as an exercise to the reader.